# App service not getting parameter value sent from JS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I'm working on the ASP.NET Zero (.NET Core 2.0 & jQuery) template. I'm currently moving my working code from the .NET MVC5 template into this .NET Core version.

I'm running into an issue with a couple of my app service calls from JavaScript.
I ran the app in debug and captured screenshots of JS and C# showing how the value is not getting to the C# code.
The first image below shows one such JS call to my app service method `getCompanies` — here you can see that the `Filter` parameter for `getCompanies` clearly has a value loaded.
[image]

Now when the debug reaches the C# code for `GetCompanies`, the parameter `Filter` is `null`.
[image]

I have not run into this type of issue before in the .NET MVC5 version. This is something I have only run into in the .NET Core version. Any ideas on how to fix this or where to look?

## Update

I checked the Network tab in Chrome and Edge browsers and I do NOT see the parameter value.

Network tab from Edge browser:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter names are in **camelCase** for [Client Proxies](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/AspNet-Core#client-proxies).

Use a lowercase `f` for `filter`:

```js
_companyService.getCompanies({
    filter: _filter
}).done(function (result){
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Filter property name to MyFilter and send MyFilter from client. 
(Sometimes reserved keywords are preventing model binding in asp.net core)..

you can use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see the final request goes to server.

A blog post explaining binding.
https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/